# Reporting tools for web visits to show clients

Tags: reporting, pixel, web-analytics-tools

I have a web portal in which I create content for different clients.  For example, I have articles about dentist A, or car mechanic A, with each targeting different keywords on these pages.

Is there a reporting or web analytics tool that would allow me to create reports by keyword and/or certain webpages and allow clients to log in and see this information?

For example, a report that would show all the Dentist keywords, and another all keywords for Mechanic.

Currently I am using Google Analytics, but is not very user friendly for this type of reporting.  What I am doing now is logging in to my GA account, creating a report for the keywords and emailing to client, which is not very efficient.

I am wondering if anyone knows about a pixel tracking reporting package out there for this need or any other way of getting the clients this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While searching online I found this [link](http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/tools/free-website-analytics/) which gives you a list of the top free web analytics tools.

I choose to work with statcounter which is exactly what I was looking for.  I can open a free account for a client and include their tracking script on individual pages.